# Why was the question "Why was Jake and the Never Land Pirates cancelled?" migrated to Movies?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

Although cross-posting is frowned upon, it is considered acceptable to re-ask that question on to a new Stack Exchange site if you feel that the answers you received from the earlier time do not meet your requirements or expectations.

**Why then was this question migrated to Movies.SE?**

[Why was "Jake and the Never Land Pirates" cancelled?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217130/why-was-jake-and-the-never-land-pirates-cancelled)

Comment: You assume OP _was_ indeed dissatisfied with the answer given earlier on Movies. Can you offer any evidence to back up this bold statement? As it stands, this reads more like your own headcanon.

Comment: @Jenayah - Why would they re-ask it if they were happy with the answer?

Comment: In no particular order, 1/ Forgot they asked 2/mistakenly thought they had asked here but couldn't locate it 3/couldn't be arsed to track it back 4/troll 5/can't access M&TV for some reason 6/thought posting it again would make each site richer...

Comment: @Jenayah - All of those are a bit of a reach. Given that the answer on Movies is of such a poor quality, it seems obvious that they were re-asking due to a lack of a decent response.

Comment: Isn't the basic principal that if you are dissatisfied with an answer you add a bounty to promote a new one....not cross -post?

Comment: @Paulie_D - It was discussed on Meta:SE that if you were dissatisfied with the answers you were getting, you could re-ask onto another stack **after a reasonable amount of time.**

Answer (score 12):

I'm not a mod so I can't speak for the exact reasons this happened but looking at it, it does makes sense.

[Consensus appears to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/345161) do not cross post 99% of the time with the only times being appropriate are:

- if you delete and re-ask.
- if you edit it to tailor it to the second site and/or explain why the original question didn't get a satisfactory answer on the other site.

This doesn't appear to have met those criteria. In fact if anything the cross posted question here was of worse quality than the original question over on Movies.SE.

It was probably migrated instead of deleted outright just so they could preserve the answers that were posted here. One of the answers was mainly a repeat of information so now looks weird on the merged question but the other, yours, was of high quality and so preserving this information rather than deleting outright was a good thing.

Comment: Mine was the low-quality one, of course, just quoting the other answer (which became weird when it got assigned to same question as that answer). :-P Such is life.

Answer (score 12):

> it is considered acceptable to re-ask that question on to a new Stack Exchange site if you feel that the answers you received from the earlier time do not meet your requirements or expectations.

`citation-needed`

This is a classic case of cross-posting. The questions might be worded differently, but "why was this [4-season] show cancelled" and "why did they not make a fifth season" are equivalent. There was no effort to tailor the question to *this* site specifically in order to differentiate it from the previous question, which might have made it acceptable to cross-post if the questions were sufficiently different.

Ordinarily in cross-posting cases, we close and delete one of the two questions. However, if the question has received answers on more than one site, then it's often worth migrating and merging in order to preserve good content. In this case, since the OP had posted on M&TV first and then reposted on SFF a few months later, I discussed with a M&TV mod and opted to keep their version as the "master", migrating our version over there to preserve all the answers in one place. This is standard practice for cross-posts with answers.

It's basically the same thing as we do when someone reposts the same question on the same site (close and delete the repost, merge to preserve content if applicable), only with the extra added step of migration as necessary.

Comment: (This is essentially what TheLethalCarrot already said in his answer. I'm just posting my own explanation for accountability.)